# Implementing digit by digit to find square root of input in R

Tags: r

I am trying to implement the square root of input using the digit by digit algorithm in R. I have found some pseudo code online on how to do it but it seems like I have been put in an endless loop

```
    sqrt.by.digit <- function(S, eps=1e-6) { 
    res <- 0
    d <- 1
    while ((S - res * res) > eps) {
      x <- 1
      while ((res + (x * d)) * (res + (x * d)) <= S) {
        x <- x + 1
        res <- res + (x - 1) * d
        d <- d /10
      }
    }
    res
   }
   print(sqrt.by.digit(10, 0.1))
```

1. Set res to 0
2. Set d to 1
3. Repeat steps a-d while the absolute value of (S - res*res) is greater than eps
4. Set x to 1
5. Repeat the following while (res + (x * d)) * (res + (x * d)) is less than or equal to S: Set x to x + 1
6. Set res to res + (x - 1) * d
7. Set d to d / 10
8. OUTPUT result

Comment: What pseudocode you have found?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy Its in the edited question

Comment: Read carefully the 5-th point (which is probably b in the original notation). You have to repeat x <- x+1 while the condition is met. Change your inner while loop according to that and everything works fine :)

Comment: Its confusing on what needs to be done. Relatively new to R  @storaged

Comment: Step 5. mentions only ONE operation that should be done inside of the second `while` loop. Reformulate it as: *while the following `(res + (x * d)) * (res + (x * d))` is less than or equal to `S`, repeat `set x to x + 1`*. Does it makes sense now?

Comment: @storaged You could make of your comments an answer, they fully answer the question and in the future may be helpfull to other users. (Of course, you would correct the code.)

Comment: Done, the user has already vanished, but maybe it will be helpful one day

Answer (score 0):

The code is nearly ok, but the problem hides in details. The algorithm states:

- Repeat steps a-d while the absolute value of (S - res*res) is greater
  than eps

  - Set x to 1
  - Repeat the following while (res + (x * d)) * (res + (x * d)) is less than or equal to S: Set x to x + 1
  - Set res to res + (x - 1) * d
  - Set d to d / 10

The inner loop that is described mentions only one operation that should have been performed while the condition is met, i.e. `Set x to x + 1`.

So the only change that the implementation from the question needs is shifting the parenthesis `}`, so that inner-`while` performs one operation.

```
sqrt.by.digit <- function(S, eps=1e-6) { 
  res <- 0
  d <- 1
  while ((S - res * res) > eps) {
    x <- 1
    while ((res + (x * d)) * (res + (x * d)) <= S) {
      x <- x + 1
    }
    res <- res + (x - 1) * d
    d <- d /10
  }
  res
}

sapply((0:10)^2, sqrt.by.digit)
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```